# Shopping carts in Redis

Tags: redis, key-value-store

I want to store shopping cart data in Redis.

I have this kind of data:

```
{ user_X (unique)

product_id1, product_name1, product_price1

product_id2, product_name2, product_price2

... } example of a shopping cart
```

---

```
{ user_Y (unique)

product_id1, product_name1, product_price1

product_id2, product_name2, product_price2

... } example of another shopping cart
```

Which data type should I use?

Comment: What about quantities? Can the same product appear more than once (with the same or different price) in a given cart? What types of data access patterns do you need to serve - are carts created row by row or in bulk? Do you need to update products in a cart? Do you need to fetch one cart at a time based on a user's ID or are you looking to do aggregates the contents across multiple carts? The bottom line is that there are many ways to model the data - identifying the right one requires information on what you want to do with it.

Comment: no quantity - products don't appear more than once, bulk not necessary, row by row is ok - in cart products can be added or deleted but update of some value is not necessary - only one cart per user, but obviously users can make different carts at the same time - Yes I want to identify the smartest way to model my data!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data appears to fit in nicely into the Hash data type. Use key names made up of the user's ID (the Redis convention is to separate elements in the key name using the colon, ':', character). The field names in each cart Hash should be the product ids.

Since Redis' Hashes (and all other data types for that matter) do not support nesting, the only possible data type for a Hash's field value is a String. The easiest to store your product's name and price in a String is simply to concatenate the two and use a delimiter for separation. The example above would therefore be stored in Redis similar to the below:

```
HSET cart:X id1 "name1:price1"
HSET cart:X id2 "name2:price2"

HMSET cart:Y id1 "name1:price1" id2 "name2:price2"
```

To get a user's cart, do an `HGETALL` on the key or use `HSCAN` if you have really big carts.

Comment: Ok! I think is smart, in this way when I get data I can parse the string with ":" to distinguish the name from the price. What about if I have more than one ":"? In this way I cannot accept ":" in name or price, right?

Comment: True, but you can easily work around it by choosing a different delimiter (Redis' strings are binary-safe so you can even use \x00) or craft an escape sequence (e.g. '\:') that will be used for value demarcation purposes :P

Comment: And BTW, you may find the section about shopping carts from Redis in Action useful as well: https://redislabs.com/academy/redis-in-action/part-1-getting-started/chapter-2-anatomy-of-a-redis-web-application/2-2-shopping-carts-in-redis

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will show you how to harness the power of Redis by creating a basic eCommerce shopping cart application with Node.js. Usually, the shopping cart data is stored on the client-side as a cookie. Cookies are small text files stored in a web user's browser directory or data folder. The advantage of doing this is that you wouldn't need to store such temporary data in your database. However, this will require you to send the cookies with every web request, which can slow down the request in case of large cookies.

You might find this interesting: https://developer.redislabs.com/howtos/shoppingcart/